# sql of oracle convert to sql of postgresql tool

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool for translation of Oracle PL/SQL into Postgresql PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158310/tool-for-translation-of-oracle-pl-sql-into-postgresql-pl-pgsql)

Is there the tool which converts SQL of the stored procedure of oracle into SQL of the stored procedure of postgreSQL?
Because I am a Japanese, I save it in simple English when I have you answer it.