# Convert old oracle joins to ANSI SQL joins

Tags: oracle, join, vertica

Is there a tool that would help me with rewriting thousands of lines of code?
We are going to migrate from Oracle server to Vertica and therefore the older 
Oracle joins would no longer be supported and a lot of SQL needs to be rewritten.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Toad 11.0](http://www.quest.com/toad/) (query builder) is suppose to be able to do this.  I've not use this in great detail, but for the most part it works.  i would double check any code provided by any tool as nothing is 100% fool proof.   Another promising tools that many like seems to be [swissql](http://www.swissql.com/).   No matter which tool you use, you're going to need to have lots of manual proof reading to make sure the resulting query is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Vertica's variant of SQL is the same as PostgreSQL. So you may want to see if any tools handle that already.

Here's a link that may be a good starting point: [Tool for translation of Oracle PL/SQL into Postgresql PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158310/tool-for-translation-of-oracle-pl-sql-into-postgresql-pl-pgsql)